# Reference Request: Vector Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, vector-spaces

I am a new student in the field of functional analysis. I'm looking for references that make sense for all kinds of vector spaces, such as the difference between $L^2$ and $l^2$  and others like: $C_0$ ,$C^1$, etc...

Thanks.

Comment: The keywords would be: normed vector spaces, Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces...rather than vector spaces. For instance, $L^2(0,1)$ and $\ell^2$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: How experienced are you in analysis? The thing is, functional analysis is typically not the study of *specific* linear spaces, but rather of more general properties of large classes of linear spaces (in particular, locally convex spaces, Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces). I guess I just mean to say that you might not find what you're looking for in a book just about functional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a book and are not afraid of thick, old books, try to get your hands on a copy of "Linear Operators I" by Dunford and Schwarz (from 1958, I think). It's dense but contains a lot of cool and unique stuff.